# Why does my promise chain run concurrently, not sequentially

Tags: node.js, concurrency, promise, async-await

I'm new to node and promises, so any help would be appreciated!

I'm trying to:

1. get an access token from an API
2. send the access token to the same API for a URL
3. poll the URL for some data

I thought the sensible way to do this would be a promise chain (Note I haven't implemented the polling yet, I just console.log at intervals for now while I'm getting this working. Also the request bodies aren't included below, but aren't a problem):

```
const request = require('request');

// get access token
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request.post({
    json_request
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) console.error(error);
    console.log("got access token"));
    resolve(JSON.parse(body).accessToken);
  });
})

// use access token to get url
.then(
  (accessToken) => {
    request.post({
      json_request_with_access_token
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) console.error(error);
      console.log("got URL");
      return JSON.parse(body).url;
    })
  }
)

// Poll URL
.then(
  (reportURL) => {
    console.log("I'm here!");
    setInterval(() => {
     console.log("Report URL: ".concat(reportURL));
    }, 10000);    // setInterval waiting time
  }
)
```

The problem is that the last promise in the chain is running before the middle one has finished. So the output to the console is:

```
got access token
I'm here!
got URL
report URL: undefined
```

if "I'm here!" is printed before "got URL", then while the 2nd promise is running the code must move on to the last promise. The problem is it doesn't have the URL yet. I don't understand how to run these after one another, rather than concurrently. I've tried making the three promises into 3 separate functions, then wrapping them in one async main() function, where

```
async function main() {
  let accessToken = await getAccessToken();
  let url = await getURL(accessToken);
  await pollReport(url);
}
```

but this had the same bug. Does anyone know how to fix this? Have I made a basic error somewhere? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thing is, your code is not really clean. Always check that you have the same number of opening and closing brackets and parenthesis. This would explain why your ".then"s are acting concurrently, because you're not actually chaining them.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've just checked the original code and it's fine, it was just an error in simplifying the actual request json to 'json_request' for stack overflow, and i messed up the parentheses. Sadly not the issue though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your section `// use access token to get url` and last section is not returning a promise. It is a callback in then which doesn't return promise. you need to wrap it in `new Promise`.

I would highly recommend to move from `request` package as it has now been deperecated. use some modenr day packages which has inbuilt support for promises and will also make your life easier. Like `got`, `axios` etc.